# Ionic 2, problema con navbar

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Hola a todos mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo una pantalla donde tengo un popover que cuando lo abro hay un ítem que se llama acerca de que llama a otra pantalla. El problema es que cuando se muestra la pantalla el navbar se hace angosto solo para iOS porque en Android funciona perfectamente. ¿Alguien ha tenido un problema similar para que me pueda ayudar?

[image: Esta es la pantalla donde se muestra el popover]

[image: Aquí se ve el navbar angosto (iOS)]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Tuve que mostrar la pantalla "Acerca de" en un modal. No era la solución que quería pero me sirvió.